# Convert Month, Year to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I wrote some code last year that search to and from taking in dates like 'January, 2018' and converting it to the first day of the month. I have now found there to be a bug and my code is now return the current year, not the searched year.

```
$From = "January, 2018";
$From = strtotime($From);
$From = date('Y-m-01', $From);
```

This returns this: 2019-01-01 when I want 2018-01-01

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: There's no "day" in from, so you can't convert like that.

Comment: Take out the comma, or insert a " 1" just before it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date string is missing the day, so you could add the day yourself and specify the format it is in right now to create a date object. Then you can display that date object in whatever format you want:

```
$From = "January, 2018";
$From = DateTime::createFromFormat('d, M, Y','1,'.$From);
$From = $From->format('Y-m-d');
// Outputs 2018-01-01
```

Read more about createFromFormat here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php